# Getting a HTTP 400 error on a jetty application

Tags: website, jetty

One of the jetty applications in my workplace, which runs on an Ubuntu Server, is unresponsive (users which are going to http://[PATH_TO_MY_APP]/ are waiting and waiting and after a long while they get error code 400.

I'm new at this subject and I'm not sure how to begin troubleshooting this error.
I can say that I get this error from multiple computers in the network and they're all windows machines secured with up to date anti-virus software, etc.

I've tried cleaning cache and cookies on the client machines but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What version of Jetty is this?

Comment: it's version 8.1.8

Answer (score 1):

One thing worth checking is what version of Jetty you're using. Depending on your version, there is a known issue with certain versions where accessing the server with URLs that do not include a trailing slash "/", will encounter the 400 error code as you've described.

See [here](https://github.com/robfletcher/betamax/issues/61) for more on this particular problem. Here's a link to the actual issue filed on Jetty's bug tracker, [JETTY-1553](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1533).